# why do I see SignalR stuff on the network tab when I am not even using signal R on my app

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I am creating a SPA using John Papa SPA Videos from Plural Sight.
I created a simple asp.net web application (empty), and then I added
entity framework
web api
jquery
modernizr
web optimization
twitter bootstrap
fontawesome
Razor

Please note I havent added any single SignalR nugetpackage.

However I see some signalR activity on the browser, why?

see here: http://screencast.com/t/yFlMfFoqBl

My web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>

</configuration>
```

I am using VS 2013 Update 3 RTM.

And my packages:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.4.1.9004" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" version="6.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="font-awesome" version="4.1.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Compact" version="4.0.8854.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.7.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="5.0.4" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Twitter.Bootstrap" version="3.0.1.1" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.5.2" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using VS2013, then this is almost certainly caused by the Browser-Link feature in Visual Studio, that enables you to view client side changes on your website, Without refreshing it. VS uses SignalR to accomplish this. It is nothing to worry about.